# cant add a shape layer into a view's layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer, cashapelayer

I'm working on `CAShapeLayer` by creating a layer using CAShapeLayer like following:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(150, 50, 200, 200);
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

However, when I execute the codes and I cant see my `shapeLayer` in the simulator/device.
What I am missing here.

PS : If I am using `CALayer *shapeLayer = [CALayer layer];` it works.Confused

Comment: Did you read the docs on CALayer and CAShapeLayer, or did you just blrrrrpjstfrsts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a path to it, like

```
 shapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) 
                                              cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
```

A shaped layer needs a shape…

---

I put this in my View Controller and it works fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(150, 50, 200, 200);
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;

    NSUInteger radius = 90;
    shapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                                 cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];   
}
```

[image]

If you change the path like

```
shapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shapeLayer.bounds].CGPath;
```

it'll result in

[image]

Comment: thanks, if I tried `CALayer    *shapeLayer  =   [CALayer layer];` it works.Why CALayer does not need the path.

Comment: because it defines the shape